# Error in AspNetCore.Reporting: 'System.Windows.Forms' Assembly Not Found When Generating Charts in RDLC Report with .NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, reporting, nuget-package, .net-5, rdlc

I am encountering an issue while attempting to generate charts in an RDLC report within my .NET 5 project using the AspNetCore.Reporting package. The error message that I am facing is as follows:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have thoroughly tested the data source and confirmed that other components, such as tables, generate without any issues. However, I seem to be facing this problem specifically with chart generation. My project is built in .NET 5, and I am utilizing the AspNetCore.Reporting package for RDLC report rendering.

I suspect that this issue might be related to the lack of compatibility between the AspNetCore.Reporting package and the .NET 5 environment, especially in handling chart components. However, I am unsure of the exact cause of the problem and how to resolve it.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to overcome this issue and successfully generate charts within my RDLC reports using the AspNetCore.Reporting package in .NET 5. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: This seems to be a issue on .net 5 and onwards .net core rdlc reporting can't seem to generate chart inside the report. I have implemented a microservice which is in .net 4 to handle chart generation for the rdlc reports.